# Setting up push notifications with pubnub

Tags: pubnub

I am trying to setup push notifications with PubNub on a react-native project. However calling the push.addChannels() method gives me the error 403 with "PNAccessDeniedCategory".

I have tried turning off the access manager but still get the same result. Not to sure if I am passing the correct params though.

I have setup push notifications with apple and uploaded the cert.pem file to PubNub.

```
pubnub.push.addChannels({
        channels: ['ch.staff'],
        device: 'ECID-OF-DEVICE-HERE',
        pushGateway: 'apns' // apns, gcm, mpns
      }, function(status) {
        if (status.error) {
          console.log("operation failed w/ error:", status);
        } else {
          console.log("operation done!")
        }
      });
```

I can send and receive standard messages without issue, it is just this which doesn't work.

I am following the docs here:

https://www.pubnub.com/docs/javascript/mobile-gateway-sdk-v4#Provisioning_devices_with_channel_names_per_lang_Examples

My main questions are.

Do I need to grant access to use this method and how do I do that?
Is the device field supposed to be the ECID?

Answer (score 0):

## PubNub Mobile Push + Access Manager

Access Manager is denying access because the client device's auth-key does not have `read` permissions (or it doesn't have an auth-key at all).

Either disable Access Manager until you are ready to implement permission granting to auth-keys for your clients by your server, or grant `read` permission for the client's auth-key for the channels it needs to register for push on (and optionally subscribe to).

For full details see the [PubNub Nub operations/permissions mapping](https://www.pubnub.com/knowledge-base/discussion/644/how-do-i-enable-add-on-features-for-my-keys) in the PubNub JavaScript SDK docs Access Manager tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

The grant permissions would look something like this:

```
pubnub.grant(
{
    channels: ['ch.staff'],
    authKeys: ['clientAuthKey'],
    read: true, // false to disallow
    write: true, // false to disallow
},
function (status) {
    // handle state setting response
    console.log('Status', status)
}
);
```